# How to schedule jobs using command prompt and manage resources?

Tags: windows, ssh, command-line, jobs, job-scheduling

I'm trying to understand how job scheduling works. From my understanding, I need to schtasks to schedule jobs, but I'm not really sure how to deal with my specific problem.

Essentially, I want my team to schedule computation jobs that takes into account the number of cores currently in use. One of our VMs has two CPUs with 12 cores each. We started SSHing in the VM from our local machines, so the next step would be the manage resources and jobs. I'm not really sure where to start.

Let's say I need to schedule a job that takes 2 to 3 days. How do I do this? And what is a good way of managing resources? Let's say I want to use only one of the CPUs so that my coworker can use the other CPU, how is this done?

Lastly, all of our code is in Python. So should we be using Python-specific commands to deal with job scheduling (in other words, is there a Python approach that's simpler)?

I know I'm not asking too direct a question. My apologies. I spent some time researching online, but everything I've come across is either hard to understand or not really useful. I'm likely just not searching for the right thing.

Anyways, thank you in advance! :)

Comment: are you able to run powershell on the box? if so - you might find some inspiration [from this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61673254/scheduling-a-powershell-script-to-run-every-20-minutes)